# Adding multiple array values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my form

```
<form method="post" action="collect_vals.php">
    <div id="input_fields">
        <div><input type="text" placeholder="unit" name="unit[]"> <input type="text" placeholder="price" name="price[]"><input type="text" placeholder="total" name="total[]"> <span class="fa fa-plus-circle" id="add_field"></span></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d9bhsL4o/1/

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name=unit]").keyup(function() {
            var unit = new Array();
            var qty = new Array();
            $("input[name=unit]").each(function() {
                unit.push($(this).val());
            });
            $("input[name=qty]").each(function() {
                qty.push($(this).val());
            });

            var total = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i <unit.length; i++) {
                var inp=unit[i]*qty[i];
                ("total["+i+"].value="+inp.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Trying to multiply two values and keep on third. Does not working. What the wrong with the code

Comment: updated bro. pls check now

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5vh0guvh/)

Comment: The OP simply says "Does not working". There is no problem description. 
And it has 6 upvotes... Something seems wrong...

Comment: and not a word on the expected behaviour

Comment: @Tushar This is your seven account?:)

Comment: @AlexChar Noooooooo!

Comment: lol. @Tushar why you have so many.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Go to [users](http://stackoverflow.com/users) and search for _Tushar_, you'll see many users, don't you say these are mine :P

Comment: @Tushar and you're the 1st one in the list :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am attached class definition inside html both rendered and appended element. I tweak around your html code and use this to total up all values respectively :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="unit" name="unit[]" class="a">
<input type="text" placeholder="price" name="price[]" class="a">
<input type="text" placeholder="total" name="total[]" class="total">
```

**JS**

```
......
......
$("#input_fields").append('<input type="text" placeholder="unit" name="unit[]" class="a"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="price" name="price[]" class="a">
  <input type="text" placeholder="total" name="total[]" class="total">
  <span id="remove" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></span</div>');
......
......

// capture both unit AND price keyup
$("#input_fields").on('keyup', '.a', function () {
    // add current keyup textbox also into stack
    var all = $(this).siblings('input.a').addBack();
    var sum = 1;
    // loop over those element
    all.each(function(i,e){
        // sum both values
        sum *= $(e).val();
    });
    // finally filtered textbox with total class
    // and assign the output
    $(this).nextAll('.total').val(sum);
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/6vvn4xmd/)

Comment: You forgot to put `div` wrapper to wrap around input inside `.append('<div><input type="text"...`. See updated demo.

Comment: i was multiplying. But u added. Pls fix that

Comment: @VIITushar, Weird If its not working Why did you accepted the answer? Accepted answer means problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You should traverse the DOM, there are multiple ways to travese DOM. Here I have used [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get `total` and `qty`

```
$("#input_fields").on('keyup', "input[name='unit[]']", function () {
    var unit = $(this).val();
    var price = $(this).siblings("input[name='price[]']").val();
    $(this).siblings("input[name='total[]']").val(unit * price);
});
```

Comment: @https://jsfiddle.net/zgwrau8h/, Since you are using `[]` as attribute value selector wrap them in quotes like `"input[name='unit[]']"` and second attribute value were not correct